# how to set up laravel-vue project using @vitejs/plugin-vue plugin

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs3, vite, laravel-9

I have setup the laravel project with vuejs using @vitejs/plugin-vue plugin, The issue I'm facing is how to manage endpoints between client(vue 3) and backend (laravel 9).

When click register at first time it return the register.vue
[image]

When page refresh it returns back 404 error.

[image]

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        @vite(['resources/js/app.js','resources/css/app.css'])
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>

    <header>
        <!--    load navbar here -->
        <nav>
            <RouterLink to="/register">Register</RouterLink>
            <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        
        <RouterView/>

    </main>

</template>
```

**router.js**

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from "vue-router";
import Register  from "../components/Register.vue";
import App  from "../../views/App.vue";

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'app',
            component: App
        },{
            path: '/register',
            name: 'register',
            component: Register
        }
    ]
})
export default router
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix.
In **routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
  return view('welcome');
})->where("any",".*");
```

[see here](https://dev.to/tanzimibthesam/how-to-install-vuevue-routertailwind-with-laravel-9vite-47ec)